# Can not instantiate proxy of class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xunit, xunit.net

To test my controller project, I created an xUnit project and wrote a function and decorated it with the Fact attribute:

```
        [Fact]
        public void GetAllTest()
        {
            var mockMediator = new Mock<Mediator>();
            var controller = new ResidenceController(mockMediator.Object);
            var result = controller.GetAll();
            Assert.IsType<IEnumerable<ResidenceDto>>(result.Result);
            
        }
```

When I run this test get error:

> Can not instantiate proxy of class: MediatR.Mediator.
> Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')
> ---- System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.MediatorProxy' not found.

My controller inherits from a custom API controller. Within the methods, I use MediatR to send commands.

Comment: you can't mock the `Mediator` class like that because it has no parameterless constructor - as the error message indicates

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your `ResidenceController` but I believe your problem is because you are using concrete implementation of `Mediator` class instead of the `IMediator`.

In `ResidenceController`:

```
private IMediator mediator;
public ResidenceController(IMediator mediator)
{
    this.mediator = mediator
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

Then in your test:

```
[Fact]
public void GetAllTest()
{
    var mockMediator = new Mock<IMediator>();
    var controller = new ResidenceController(mockMediator.Object);
    var result = controller.GetAll();
    Assert.IsType<IEnumerable<ResidenceDto>>(result.Result);
}
```

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) for more detail